# How to obtain Phoenix table data via HBase REST service

Tags: rest, hadoop, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I created a HBase table using the Phoenix JDBC Driver in the following code snippet:

```
    Class.forName("org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
    Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:serverurl:/hbase-unsecure");
    System.out.println("got connection");

    conn.createStatement().execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS phoenixtest (id BIGINT not null primary key, test VARCHAR)");

    int inserted = conn.createStatement().executeUpdate("UPSERT INTO phoenixtest VALUES (5, '13%')");
    conn.commit();

    System.out.println("Inserted or updated " + inserted + " rows");

    ResultSet rst = conn.createStatement().executeQuery("select * from phoenixtest");

    while (rst.next()) {
      System.out.println(rst.getString(1) + " " + rst.getString(2));
    }
```

The table is created and the table-looping works fine.

Now I tried to obtain the table data also via HBase REST services as I know it from "native" HBase programming.

The url `http://server-url:12345/PHOENIXTEST/schema` works fine and gives back the requested table info.

But when I try e.g. `http://server-url:12345/PHOENIXTEST/5` (5 was the key of the first inserted row, see code above), I get a `Not found` message back.

How can I obtain the data via the HBase REST service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have an issue with how Phoenix encodes data it stores in an HBase table, vs how the native REST API will try and find a key.

Looking at the Phoenix documentation on [data types](http://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#bigint_type) for BIGINT it says:

> The binary representation is an 8 byte long with the sign bit flipped
>   (so that negative values sorts before positive values).

So you should probably take a look at what has actually been inserted into your table. The HBase REST API is probably looking for a key using a different encoding and thus can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

You really should get your data from phoenix table using phoenix not HBase. Phoenix use is custom encoding for it's [Integer](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#integer_type) and [BigInt](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#bigint_type) also [salting](https://phoenix.apache.org/language/datatypes.html#bigint_type) (if you use one).

Phoenix also mostly use byte for storing data and StringBinary for encoding it. So, lot of chance that your key is not 5 but \x80\x00\x00\x05(Integer)